# SQL Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need make this query:

`declare @no as varchar(100)`

```
set @no='11,2,23'

select * from ft (nolock) where fno in (@no)
```

but have this error all the time: Error converting data type varchar to numeric

The fno is numeric in the table

Comment: @no is declared as varchar, you could do like this Exec ('select * from dbo.CM_Address (nolock) where ID in ('+@no+')')

Comment: You should read this article on arrays in SQL Server http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html Whilst it may not provide you with exact T-SQL to solve your problem, it will certainly help you understand why your current SQL doesn't work and how you should fix it.

Comment: There is a difference between multiple parameters separated by commas, and a single string parameter that happens to *contain* commas. This is as true in SQL as it is in any other programming language I can think of. Why would you expect SQL Server to inspect the single parameter and decide to automagically convert it into multiple parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly select data like `in (@no)` since `LIKE` expects data as a table. Please try:

```
declare @no nvarchar(max)
set @no='11,2,23'

select * from ft (nolock) where fno in (    
    SELECT 
         Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS CVS  
    FROM  
    (
         SELECT
             CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@no, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS CVS  
    ) AS A CROSS APPLY CVS.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish the query you are trying to create with a table variable instead of just a varchar variable:

```
declare @t table (
        n int
)

insert into @t
values
 (1)
,(2)
,(3)

select
        *
from someTable
where n in (
        select 
            n
    from @t
)
```